# Show windows application in a php file

Tags: php

I have searched everywhere for the answer but cant find any reference anywhere

i am building a local database and like to include a page that shows a piece of software that will be installed on windows is there away so show this such as a iframe.

sorry if this question is very vague but i am not sure what this would be called.

There will be no interaction within php to the application and the server is ran of the same windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible.
what you can do, and only if the software supports it, is to send arguments by the command line using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and show the user the response.

```
exec("path/to/software.exe -argA -argB",$result,$error);
var_dump($result); //<--the software response.
```